# Weird ouput on updating json dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have such a json dictionary:

```
nxt = {"name": names[a], "profile_id": indata["profile_id"], "firstname": firstnames[a], "middlename": middlenames[a], "lastname": lastnames[a],
       "e_mail": e_mails[a], "phone_number": phone_numbers[a], "location": locations[a], "sex": genders[a],
       "user_id": indata["user_id"], "updated_by": indata["username"]}
```

I want to update the dictionary:

```
cpnxt = nxt
del cpnxt['profile_id'], cpnxt['user_id'], cpnxt['updated_by']
nxt.update({"jsondata": cpnxt})
data.append(nxt)
```

I expect to get such an output:

```
nxt = {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': "{'phone_number': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'middl...ame': 'John Smith', 'e_mail': '', 'location': ''}", 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}
```

But I get such an output:

```
nxt = {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {...}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}
```

This is really annoying. I couldn't become aware of where I have done the mistake.

How should I fix this annoying problem?

Comment: I didn't read your whole code, but just so you know, `cpnxt = nxt` does not create a deep copy of `nxt`. Any changes you make to `cpnxt` will also happen to `nxt`. Use the `dict.copy` method, or the `deepcopy` module, if you want to make a copy of a dict that isn't a referential duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment creates a new reference to the same object, not a copy. If you wanted to alter a dictionary but preserve a copy, create a copy explicitly:

```
cpnxt = nxt.copy()
```

This creates a *shallow* copy; a new dictionary, with the keys and values copied across unaltered. You can alter what keys are in that new copy, but if you altered the values (say, append to a list, or made changes to the `nxt['jsondata']` nested dictionary) you'll still see those changes shared.

In your case, you only deleted keys, and replaced the value of another key, so a shallow copy should suffice. If you need a *deep* copy, where values are recursively copied too, use the [`copy.deepcopy()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).